# PHP email message not working with HTML

Tags: php, forms, email

Trying to get my form to email working, but when I add this part of the code

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

the email won't send. When I remove it, the email sends, but all the tags show up. Any idea what the problem is?

My php code is below:

```
$name =  $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone =  $_POST['phone'];
$injury =  $_POST['injury'];
$message = $_POST['message'];  

$myemail = 'example@gmail.com';

$subject = 'Brain Damage Info Free Evaluation Form';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$email_message = '<html><body>';
$email_message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$email_message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";
$email_message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
$email_message .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['phone']) . "</td></tr>";
$email_message .= "<tr><td><strong>Injury:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['injury']) . "</td></tr>";
$email_message .= "<tr><td><strong>Description of Injury:</strong> </td><td>" . $_POST['message'] . "</td></tr>";
$email_message .= "</table>";
$email_message .= "</body></html>";



$sent = mail($myemail,$subject,$email_message,$headers);
```

Comment: `charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";` *might,* just *might* be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
        $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

with this i do not get such errors. I think the charset is the problem.